# How can we make an argument of an inner function optional depending on an argument of the outer function?

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

There is a function that returns another one. I want to make a parameter of the inner function optional if a parameter of the outer one is present and mandatory otherwise.

```
function outer(a?: number) {
  // How can we make b here optional if a is present and mandatory otherwise?
  return function inner(b: number) {
    // some stuff
  };
}
```

Of course, we can just return two functions with different signatures inside the outer function, but I wonder if there is a better solution.

**UPDATE**

The solution with function overloading works for this simple example.

```
function outer(a: number): (b?: number) => any;
function outer(a?: number): (b: number) => any;
function outer(a?: number) {
  return function inner(b?: number) {
    // some stuff
  };
}

outer(1)(2);
outer(1)();
outer()(1);
```

What about the real example with Redux:

```
import { AsyncThunk, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type RecipeGetter = () => string[];
type ThunkWithOptionalRecipeIds = AsyncThunk<
  Record<string, string>,
  string[] | undefined,
  Record<string, never>
>;
type ThunkWithRequiredRecipeIds = AsyncThunk<
  Record<string, string>,
  string[],
  Record<string, never>
>;

function getFetchRecipesByIdThunk(
  typePrefix: string,
  recipeIdGetter: RecipeGetter,
): ThunkWithOptionalRecipeIds;
function getFetchRecipesByIdThunk(
  typePrefix: string,
  recipeIdGetter?: RecipeGetter,
): ThunkWithRequiredRecipeIds;
function getFetchRecipesByIdThunk(
  typePrefix: string,
  recipeIdGetter?: RecipeGetter,
) {
  return createAsyncThunk(typePrefix, async (recipeId?: string[]) => {
    // some stuff
  }
}
```

It seems that it doesn't work here:
[Screenshot from the code editor with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0XkR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with TypeScript method overloads. Simply declare all possibilities of arguments and return values like so:

```
function outer(a: number): (b: number) => any;
function outer(): (b?: number) => any;
function outer(a?: number) {
  return function inner(b?: number) {
    // some stuff
  };
}
```

and you can change the `any` to whatever the closure will actually return

VSCode correctly erroring on the second line because it requires an argument

[image: typescript code]

Comment: Op is asking for `function outer(a: number): (b?: number) => any;` and `function outer(): (b: number) => any;`, the opposite of what you have. It should error on the first, not the second.

Comment: Function overloading works for this simple example. But I've got an error when tried to apply this approach to the more elaborate case. I've updated my question.